# Why this integral is equal to zero?

Tags: gauge-theory, gauge-symmetry, brst, functional-derivatives

Recently I have read that for gauge-invariant functional (under transformations of some $SU(n)$ group) $R(A) = R(F_{\mu \nu}^{a})$ contains only gauge field $A_{\mu}^{a}$ satisfies the identity
$$
\tag 1 \int d^{4}x\frac{\delta R(A)}{\delta A_{\mu}^{a}}(D_{\mu} c)^{a} = 0, \quad D_{\mu}^{ab} = \delta^{ab}\partial_{\mu} - A_{\mu}^{c}f_{abc}.
$$
Here $c$ is ghost field.

Why $(1)$ is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $R[A]$ is gauge invariant, the variation of $R[A]$ is zero when $A^a_{\mu}$ undergoes the infinitesimal gauge transformation $A^a_{\mu}\rightarrow A^a_{\mu} + \epsilon (D_{\mu}\alpha)^a$ where $\alpha^a$ is any Lie algebra valued field and $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal parameter. The variation of $R[A]$ under this gauge transformation is 
$$0=\delta R = \epsilon\int d^{4}x\frac{\delta R[A]}{\delta A_{\mu}^{a}}(D_{\mu} \alpha)^{a} .$$ $\alpha^a$ can be any Lie algebra value field, including a ghost field. Per Qmechanic's comment, when $\alpha^a$ is a Grassmann field, such as a ghost field, $\epsilon$ should be taken to be a Grassmann paramerer so that the product $\epsilon \alpha^a$ has even Grassmann parity. Your equation (1) follows from setting $\alpha^a = c^a.$

Comment: Comment to the answer (v1): Note that $\alpha^a$ and $c^a$ have opposite Grassmann-parity: The gauge-parameter $\alpha^a$ is Grassmann-even, while the Faddeev-Popov ghost $c^a$ is Grassmann-odd. Therefore it is necessary to insert a Grassmann-odd parameter to have equality.